# Why is == overridden in System.Double but not in System.Int32 and what are the ramifications of that?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

In C#  Why does `Double` override `==` but `Int32` does not, and what is the effect?

I look at the msdn library.

I see this link about double which doesn't say much [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) (though I understand double is a shorthand for the `Double` object).. It doesn't show methods for example..

but this link on `System.Double` does mention what I'm looking for [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It shows the Equality operator taking doubles, so overloaded.

Image For `Double` in MSDN, then after Methods (before listing Fields), it shows Operators, and it shows equality operator is overridden

[image]

and I can click Equality under "Operators" and [it says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.op_equality.aspx)

```
public static bool operator ==(
    double left,
    double right
)
```

Whereas when I look at `System.Int32`
Image For `Int32` in MSDN is below

[image]

See in that image, (the page for `System.Int32`) it looks like `==` is not overridden.

Why, and what are the ramifications of this?

Comment: It almost looks like the Documentation is incomplete or there is stuff going on behind the scenes because from the doc page it says: "The Int32 type supports standard mathematical operations such as addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, negation, and unary negation. Like the other integral types, the Int32 type also supports the bitwise AND, OR, XOR, left shift, and right shift operators.
You can use the standard numeric operators to compare two Int32 values, or you can call the CompareTo or Equals method."

Comment: @TyCobb the guy posting using ILSpy showed that method existing, so might that suggest it's not generated code.. he also suggests it decompiles. And also, i am not doubting that it calls the Equals method, but can you quote what shows that?

Comment: @TyCobb looking at what Matt posted. The first and third WriteLine() give a different result. So  == and .Equals don't behave the same. So,  == does not call `.Equals(..)` , agree?

Comment: @barlop yep no doubt. And TyCobb has shown that with In32 also, == doesn't call .Equals. No reason to think it happens for any of them.

Comment: You cannot actually call the operator, the C# compiler has built-in knowledge of the value types and always emits Opcodes.Ceq.  They merely act as documentation place-holders, useful to document the weirdo behavior of the IEEE-754 standard.

Comment: @HansPassant So the overloaded == methods with a body are fakes of some kind, that exist as a reminder  - people look at them and think "what's the point of this method, that's weird" and then that documents the fact that IEEE 754 has weird rules for == when involving NaN  which affects non-whole numbers?!;-) I don't really see those methods documenting it. Though I see they are only there in number types where NaN applies

Comment: The best way to see this is to look at Artfunkle's post.  Note how operator==() is implemented by calling operator==().  That would of course bomb your program with this site's name if the C# compiler actually uses the operator :)

Comment: @HansPassant yes I noticed that, and even if it could execute and it called some other == then it's not telling much. I still don't how it helps re documentation, so, is it a fraud there to create a documentation stub in HTML which they could make more descriptive and add about IEEE 754, then they ran out of energy? I don't see how they did the fraud method just for documentation but didn't document it in the code or msdn library. (only in the c# spec which doesn't need a fraudulent code stub)

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason is because of  the Double.NaN.

For the [== operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.op_equality.aspx): MSDN says: If two Double.NaN values are tested for equality by using the equality operator(==), the result is false; two Double.NaN values are not considered equal. If they are tested for equality by calling the Equals method, the result is true. When you want to determine whether the value of a Double is not a number (NaN), an alternative is to call the IsNaN method.

So the == operator and the Equals methods of Double have different behavior regards to Double.NaN, I think this why == is override for double. As for int, there's no such special case.

The code to demo the differences:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("NaN == NaN: {0}", Double.NaN == Double.NaN); 
      Console.WriteLine("NaN != NaN: {0}", Double.NaN != Double.NaN); 
      Console.WriteLine("NaN.Equals(NaN): {0}", Double.NaN.Equals(Double.NaN)); 
      Console.WriteLine("! NaN.Equals(NaN): {0}", ! Double.NaN.Equals(Double.NaN)); 
      Console.WriteLine("IsNaN: {0}", Double.IsNaN(Double.NaN));

      Console.WriteLine("\nNaN > NaN: {0}", Double.NaN > Double.NaN); 
      Console.WriteLine("NaN >= NaN: {0}", Double.NaN >= Double.NaN); 
      Console.WriteLine("NaN < NaN: {0}", Double.NaN < Double.NaN);
      Console.WriteLine("NaN < 100.0: {0}", Double.NaN < 100.0); 
      Console.WriteLine("NaN <= 100.0: {0}", Double.NaN <= 100.0); 
      Console.WriteLine("NaN >= 100.0: {0}", Double.NaN > 100.0);
      Console.WriteLine("NaN.CompareTo(NaN): {0}", Double.NaN.CompareTo(Double.NaN)); 
      Console.WriteLine("NaN.CompareTo(100.0): {0}", Double.NaN.CompareTo(100.0)); 
      Console.WriteLine("(100.0).CompareTo(Double.NaN): {0}", (100.0).CompareTo(Double.NaN)); 
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       NaN == NaN: False 
//       NaN != NaN: True 
//       NaN.Equals(NaN): True 
//       ! NaN.Equals(NaN): False 
//       IsNaN: True 
//        
//       NaN > NaN: False 
//       NaN >= NaN: False 
//       NaN < NaN: False 
//       NaN < 100.0: False 
//       NaN <= 100.0: False 
//       NaN >= 100.0: False 
//       NaN.CompareTo(NaN): 0 
//       NaN.CompareTo(100.0): -1 
//       (100.0).CompareTo(Double.NaN): 1
```

The code is also from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: can you give any compilable code samples to demonstrate that difference?

Comment: @TyCobb http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs#155 seems to not provide any useful reason for overriding == though

Comment: while that explanation explains  public bool Equals(Double obj) being overridden(as the body mentions NaN), it doesn't explain why public static bool operator ==  is overridden, as the body of that == method doesn't mention NaN. And I am asking about the == method. So so far TyCobb's theory seems strongest.

Comment: @barlop, yes, you're right. As I went through this post by Jon Skeet: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx. It says:For value types, I'd normally use == for easier-to-read code. Things would get tricky if a value type provided an overload for == which acted differently to Equals, but I'd consider such a type very badly designed to start with.

Comment: @Matt Though   if it were the case (theoretically) that Double didn't   overload == then there'd still be the problem that Equals behaves differently to ==. Because .Equals is overloaded and == isn't overloaded to equal .Equals.  It's as if they perhaps thought they should overload it to match so they did with some generated code but forgot to sanely  implement ==  (sane being, as Sir Jon Skeet says in your quote, == and .Equals acting the same).

Comment: @Matt  according to 7.10.2 in the C# 5.0 language specification  `"the operators compare the operands according to the rules of the IEEE 754 standard"`  It then describes rules that seem a bit strange, so it may be that's why they did .Equals differently, they did it their way.

Answer (score 1):

`Int32` seems to be very special in terms of .NET. The functionality that is missing from the source code is more than likely baked into core of the system.

You cannot compare structs/value-types with `==`, `>`, etc. without declaring those operators inside the struct. Because `Int32` is missing these I came to the conclusion above.

Doing a simple test and dumping the IL, they are doing the exact same comparison and no `CompareTo` or `Equals` is getting called (which I thought actually happened. I learned something!).

```
public void TestInts()
{
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    var equals = x == y;
}

.method public hidebysig 
    instance void TestInts () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2094
    // Code size 11 (0xb)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 x,
        [1] int32 y,
        [2] bool equals
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.2
    IL_0004: stloc.1
    IL_0005: ldloc.0
    IL_0006: ldloc.1
    IL_0007: ceq
    IL_0009: stloc.2
    IL_000a: ret
}

public void TestDoubles()
{
    var x = 1.7d;
    var y = 1.5d;
    var equals = x == y;
}
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void TestDoubles () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20ac
    // Code size 27 (0x1b)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] float64 x,
        [1] float64 y,
        [2] bool equals
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.r8 1.7
    IL_000a: stloc.0
    IL_000b: ldc.r8 1.5
    IL_0014: stloc.1
    IL_0015: ldloc.0
    IL_0016: ldloc.1
    IL_0017: ceq
    IL_0019: stloc.2
    IL_001a: ret
}
```

The above IL just has the standard [`ceq` opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ceq.aspx) called for both cases. By .NET standards, `Int32` should have the comparison operators declared in the source code, but it does not.

**EDIT:** It appears as though all whole-number value-types are like this. Single, Double, Decimal all have the operators specified in the source code. Int16, Int32, Int64, Byte, do not.

Comment: @barlop That is kind of similar. The only catch on that is the answer is referring to reference equality which is moot in terms of value-types.

Comment: I think your comments answered the Why of my question (your strong theory is good).. And you made  comment earlier only my question(which you deleted) which if I recall, implied (rightly) that there is no ramification. (you deleted it because within it you made the mistaken claim about .equals which you correct in your answer). But ultimately it is comments from people (including one you deleted which may have been the first though it's hard to check now!), that answered my question.

Comment: good point. I thought it'd use that because I figured an instance of System.Int32 is an object? Integer comparison operators are in 7.10.1  bool operator ==(int x, int y);  double is mentioned in 7.10.2 bool operator ==(double x, double y);

Comment: well spotted re whole numbers in your edit. So they're only in the classes with the NaNs. By the way. System.Single is float.

Comment: @barlop Yea, I decided to clean house on my comments because they didn't feel right anymore. Not sure why I slapped float in there when I had Single. Will remove.

Answer (score -1):

Using ILSpy I can see that `Double.Equals` has some additional logic to check whether either value being compared is NaN.

ILSpy also decompiles the body of `==` to this:

```
public static bool operator ==(double left, double right)
{
    return left == right;
}
```

The other operators follow the same pattern, which is weird. Perhaps a decompile error?

Comment: No need to use ILSpy when the source is available here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs#1a65cbdb09544ba1

Comment: @Nighthawk441: In this case no, but in general ILSpy has some useful navigation and analysis features. It's faster than using a website too. :)

Comment: Why did you write "The other operators follow the same pattern, which is weird. Perhaps a decompile error?" like, what did you mean? I guess you thought it looked redundant and that it might thus be an error in decompilation. Looks like it's not an error of decompilation but of design. poor design.

Comment: also i wonder if that method if it were executed would be infinitely recursive?!

Comment: Exactly. I suspect that we're looking at some hard-coded .Net runtime behaviour specific to the fundamental data types.